# Is there a theory of "sums-of-squares residues"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, quadratic-residues, sums-of-squares

The theory of quadratic residues is long- and well-studied. Recall that, [somewhat simplified] if $x,a,b$ are integers, with $0 \le a < b$, such that
$$x \equiv a^2\!\!\!\pmod{b},$$
then we say that $x$ is a *quadratic residue modulo $b$*.

Extensions have been made (or at least attempted) for higher powers, *e.g.,* cubic residues, quartic residues, *etc.* Let’s call this the **“vertical”** direction.

> **QUESTION:** Has anyone tried extending the theory of quadratic residues in the **“horizontal”** direction, *i.e.,* developing a theory around residues of more than one square?

For example, if $x,a,b,c$ are integers, with $0 \le a \le b < c$, such that
$$x \equiv a^2+b^2\!\!\!\pmod{c},$$
then we could say that $x$ is a *two-square residue modulo $c$*. Extending the thought-experiment a few steps further, the Four-Square Theorem would be equivalent to saying that every integer is a *four-square residue modulo every larger integer*, etc.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I don't understand your comment. Here's an example: say
$$a = c + d^2+e^2$$
where all are integers. Now $a$ is a two-square residue modulo $c$. So how does the Cauchy-Davenport theorem make it any easier [and/or trivial] to characterize $a$ further?

Comment: I am just saying that the set of non-two-square residues $\pmod{p}$ is empty, so there is no gain in using the concept of two-square-residue.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Ah, I see…

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Please post your comment(s) as an answer, so I can accept it and get this question out of the unanswered queue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such *horizontal* extension is not really interesting, since every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ can be represented as a sum of two squares by the [Cauchy-Davenport theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-DavenportTheorem.html). In particular in $\mathbb{F}_p$ the subset of elements that cannot be represented as the sum of two squares is empty.